# Trying To Group Core Data Fetch Results By Date

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to group core data entries by week and date. I have a core data entity named `WorkEntry` which among it's attributes I have `weekBegin` and `date`. In these I save the date it was saved on as well as the first day of the week corresponding to that date. I use `weekBegin` for the section name and I want the cells to show the dates that have entries with no duplicates. I used http://felipecypriano.com/2011/09/21/core-data-how-to-do-a-select-distinct/ as a guide. Here's my code:

Fetch Request with `returnsDistinctResults`:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)workDayFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WorkEntry"];
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WorkEntry" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"weekBegin"]];
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"weekBegin" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.distinctResults = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return fetchRequest;
}
```

which gives me an array called `distinctResults` which I use in:

`CellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.distinctResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

But I have a feeling that may not be right. When I switch to the table view in the app it crashes with this exception:

`-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c7c8a0`

I'd be really grateful for any help you guys can give. I've been going crazy trying to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Your fetch request is telling Core Data to return each result as an NSDictionary. It is likely that some place you are trying to access a result as if it were an NSString, when it is an NSDictionary - probably to read a property value (i.e. you are assuming it returned some property as each item of the results) - likely 'weekBegin'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the way you declare distinctResults property in you controller.
It may be deallocated if you use weak pointer.

Comment: I just changed it, it's still crashing